# Row count to repeat in a pattern BigQuery

Tags: sql, design-patterns, google-bigquery, repeat, rowcount

I am trying to create a row count pattern that would look something like this

```
|Id  | Row_Count |
|--- | --------- |
|1   | 1        |
|2   | 2         |
|3   | 3         |
|4   | 4         |
|5   | 5         |
|6   | 1         |
|7   | 2         |
|8   | 3         |
|9   | 4         |
|10  | 5         |
|11  | 1         |
|12  | 2         |
|13  | 3         |
|14  | 4         |
|15  | 5         |
|16  | 6         |
|17  | 1         |
|18  | 2         |
|19  | 3         |
|20  | 4         |
|21  | 5          |
```

I would like to have the count go up to 5 twice then go up to 6 once then go up to 5 twice again then 6 and so on.
I can’t seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT *, 
  IF(MOD(id - 1, 16) + 1 = 16, 6, MOD(MOD(id - 1, 16), 5) + 1) row_count 
FROM your_table
```

with output

[image]

you can test it with below

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT id
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,50)) id
)
SELECT *, 
  IF(MOD(id - 1, 16) + 1 = 16, 6, MOD(MOD(id - 1, 16), 5) + 1) row_count 
FROM your_table
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! 
How would this work if instead of ID I had a date field like 2013-01-01, 2013-01-02,…?

Answer (score 0):

> How would this work if instead of ID I had a date field like 2013-01-01, 2013-01-02,…?

Use below approach

```
SELECT day,  
  IF(MOD(pos - 1, 16) + 1 = 16, 6, MOD(MOD(pos - 1, 16), 5) + 1) row_count 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY day) pos
  FROM your_table
)
```

with output

[image]

you can test it using below

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(CURRENT_DATE() - 50, CURRENT_DATE())) day
)
SELECT day,  
  IF(MOD(pos - 1, 16) + 1 = 16, 6, MOD(MOD(pos - 1, 16), 5) + 1) row_count 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY day) pos
  FROM your_table
)
```

Below is most generic query that you can adjust to whatever configuration you need - currently it covers 5+5+9, but can easily be adjusted to any!!!

```
SELECT day,  
  CASE
    WHEN DIV(MOD(pos - 1, 19), 5) < 2 THEN MOD(MOD(pos - 1, 19), 5) + 1
    ELSE MOD(MOD(pos - 1, 19) - 1, 9) + 1
  END AS row_count 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY day) pos
  FROM your_table
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much again! This works great, but what if my patter was like 5,5,9,5,5,9,… I’m not sure how to change the ‘true’ argument of the if function to make the counter go up multiple numbers.

Comment: replace 16 with 19 (which is 5+5+9)

Comment: I replaced all 16 with 19 and got incorrect results. IF(MOD(pos - 1, 19) + 1 = 19, 6, MOD(MOD(pos - 1, 19), 5) + 1) row_count It’s showing the pattern of 1-5, 1-5, 1-5, 1-3, number 6, 1-5. Number 6 on line 19

Comment: I think I understand how this code works and I’m not sure if it will be able to do what I’m looking for. I’m looking to get the pattern of 1 to 5, 1 to 5, 1 to 9, 1 to 5, 1 to 5, 1 to 9, and so on. Would that be possible?

Comment: see update in above answer!

Comment: did this finally worked for you?

Comment: That worked, thank you! Sorry for making it difficult.